# Exercise 1.7 from Measure Theory by Le Gall

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:[0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. For every $y \in \mathbb{R}$, let $N(y) \in\{0,1,2, \ldots\} \cup\{\infty\}$ be the number of solutions of the equation $f(x)=y$. Show that $y \mapsto N(y)$ is a measurable function.

I've been working on this for several days but can't get any clues. Can anybody help me work this out?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.